How to show long text into video using ffmpeg?
I am trying to show text on a video using ffmpeg using below command.
ffmpeg -i output_video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/fa-solid-900.ttf:textfile='long_text.txt':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=10:y=5:line_spacing=10" -codec:a copy image_text_output.mp4

my long_text.txt is:
Stack Overflow1 Stack Overflow1 Stack Overflow1 Stack Overflow1 Stack Overflow1
Stack Overflow Stack Overflow2 Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Stack Overflow2
Stack Overflow Stack Overflow3 Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Stack Overflow3
Stack Overflow Stack Overflow4 Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Stack Overflow4
Stack Overflow Stack Overflow5 Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Stack Overflow5
Stack Overflow Stack Overflow6 Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Stack Overflow6
Stack Overflow Stack Overflow7 Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Stack Overflow7
Stack Overflow Stack Overflow8 Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Stack Overflow8

But on generated video, there is showing only top two rows of text. Check screenshot.

How can I show full text on video.

hmm, if text file has newline at end → echo -e "test\n">1.txt, drawtext can draw nothing
